# What is this probability notation?

Tags: probability, bayesian

I came across a conditional probability function that looks like this.

$p(y|x; \{ \sigma + \tau \})$

But I can't seem to find what the notation after the `;` and inside the `{}` is.

What is it?

Comment: Maybe the reference to book/chapter will be useful...

Comment: Its from a paper im reading. Im not asking what the sigma and tau is... I just want to know the significance of the ; and {}

Comment: Which paper is it? There is not a perfect consensus on notations between authors. Having a context will help us to answer you.

Comment: Sorry, but $\{ σ+τ \}$ is the set whose only element is (presumably) the number $σ+τ$. Having said that, the issue is the meaning of the formula in the context of probability theory, where *conditional probability* is usually denoted with $P(y | x)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA the paper can be read https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.09432.pdf there. The formula I am pointing to is in section 3.2 on page 4

Comment: Maybe [Posterior probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability)-